# How to convert uploaded html file to pdf? (django rest framework)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, html-to-pdf

I have already made html file template in the frontend (*ReactNative Expo, I would've used a library to convert the html to pdf, but expo doesn't provide one*), and by sending it to the backend I want it to be converted and saved as pdf,

I'm newbie in django but I did tried some searching, here's what I found : https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/html-template-to-pdf-in-django/ , If I go with this approach, it will be unnecessary to get multiple data from the user, since the form is very detailed, and frontend is enough to fill. I also did this approach but I don't know what I am missing (https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/save-a-auto-generated-pdf-file-django-model) , here is my code so far:

I expect the html file to be auto converted to pdf, but it still saving it as html.

UPDATE :

(models.py)

```
class Questionary(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='Documents/%Y/%m/%d/', blank = 
           False, 
            null = False)
    def generate_obj_pdf(self):
        this = Questionary.objects.get(id=self.id)
        render_to_pdf(this.file)
```

(utils.py)

```
from io import BytesIO
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
import pdfkit
from xhtml2pdf import pisa
  def render_to_pdf(your_template):
    template = get_template(your_template.html)
    response = HttpResponse(pdfkit.from_string(html), 
               content_type='application/pdf')
    return response
```

(views.py)

```
    class CreateQuestionaryAPIView(CreateAPIView):
        serializer_class = CreateQuestionarySerializer
```

(serializer.py)

```
class CreateQuestionarySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Questionary
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 4):

I use pdfkit when converting dynamic django templates to pdf's, it's very easy to use. You need to use it such as:

```py
import pdfkit

from django.template.loader import get_template


def render_to_pdf():
    # prepare your context for html template, like you do for django templates
    template = get_template('your_template.html')
    html = template.render(context=context)
    return pdfkit.from_string(html)
```

Comment: Where should I use this code? like under my serializer where it is created, or under the model itself? I also found this line useful `pdfkit.from_file('file.html', 'out.pdf')` . I don't need to make another template as I already have an html file (from the user), I just want it to be converted to pdf, is there a possibility to it?

Comment: Place this under your ```utils.py``` or ```helper.py``` is more convenient and yes you can use the html file directly in input.

Comment: I still got no luck on converting, the output is still in html file : `"file": "http://localhost:8000/media/Documents/2019/Questions_L93qhKk.html"`

Comment: change last line to ```response = HttpResponse(pdfkit.from_string(html), content_type='application/pdf')```